# What does this statement in my text mean? (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

So the problem was to integrate $\overline{z}$ over the half circle of radius 2, $ z = 2e^{i \theta}$ from $z = -2i$ to $z = 2i$. After going through the math, they say 
this integral is equal to the integral over the curve of $\frac{dz}{z}$ which is equal to $\pi i $. I don't follow how this equivalence was established. I hope I provided enough detail, still learning how to use MathJax. Thanks!

Comment: The complex conjugate of an element of the unit circle is its inverse.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: You might want to be more specific than "inverse"—e.g. multiplicative inverse or reciprocal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $z$ on this half circle $z\overline{z}=|z|^2=4$ so that $\overline{z}=\frac{4}{z}$.  Let $C$ be the contour in question.  Then we have
 $$\int_C \overline{z}=\int_C \frac{4}{z}dz=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{4}{2e^{i\theta}}d(2e^{i\theta})=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}4id\theta=4\pi i$$

I have an extra factor of $4$.  Are you sure that is not correct?

Hope that helps,

**Alternative:**

Just put in your parametrization directly, that is $z=2e^{i\theta}$.  Then we get $$\int_C \overline{z}dz=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}2e^{-i\theta}d(2e^{i\theta})=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}4id\theta=4\pi i$$

Comment: For some reason I thought this was some sort of general result, and not to do so much with the original problem :\ Thanks a lot.